# Pygame ball enlargement over time

Tags: python, pygame

I want make small game with pygame. I don’t know how I can make the ball increase over time and the spawn speed of the balls increases.
It will be like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCQp1Q8ANCM
(0:31)

```py
#ball.py
import pygame
import random
YELLOW = (225, 225, 0)

class balls:
    def draw_ball(screen, tickrate, i):
        x = random.randint(0,500)
        y = random.randint(0,500)
        first_range = 10
        range = 10

        print(i)
        if i >= 100 :
            ball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, YELLOW, (x, y), range)
```

```py
#Main.py
import pygame
import os
import random
import ball
import threading
import sys
from timeit import Timer

pygame.init()
game_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
x = 100
y = 100
os.environ['Sp_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (x,y)
size = [500, 500]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Reaction")
background = pygame.image.load("images\\background.jpg")
background_rect = background.get_rect(bottomright = (500,500))
background.set_colorkey((255,255,255)) #прозрачный слой фона
screen.blit(background,background_rect)
pygame.display.update()
run_game = True #флаг игрового цикла
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
starttime=pygame.time.get_ticks()
#timer = Timer(0.05, ball.balls.draw_ball(screen)) # 50 миллисекунд
i = 1

def quit():
            rungame = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

while run_game: #игровой цикл
    #timer.start()
    tickrate = clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
    ball.balls.draw_ball(screen,tickrate,i)
    pygame.display.update()
    if i == 100:
        i = 0
    i+=1
pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: What have you got so far? Please share code. You could have a speed variable and increase it

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4HHseC2x

Comment: https://pastebin.com/iyp0HJ8Z

Answer (score 2):

You provide little help to anyone wanting to answer your question as you provide no code.

I will assume you have a Ball object like so:

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
```

Your pygame while loop can then look something like this

```
ball = Ball(some_radius)
while 1:
    # Do pygame stuff

    ball.radius += some_number
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, pos, ball.radius)
```

This, of course, assumes you have appropriate values for some_radius, some_number, screen, color, and pos.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

First, define a class, with variables x, y, and size:

```
class GreenBall:               # Your class
    def __init__(self, x, y, size):  # The function that creates a ball at a given x and y position
        self.x = x
        self.y = y 
        self.size = size

    def grow():                   # Every time this function is called, your ball will grow
        self.size += 1

    def render():
        pygame.draw.circle(gameSurface, (0,255,0), (self.x,self.y), size)
```

Every time you want to create a new GreenBall, you could call a function like this:

```
ballList = []

def newBall(x, y):       # Initialize a new greenBall at x and y
    global ballList
    ballList.append( GreenBall( x, y, 1 ) )
```

Now, to draw your circles every tick, we need to tell them to render themselves.

```
for i in ballList:
    i.render()
```

Hopefully these chunks of code can help!

---

**Edit:**
After messing around for a bit I came up with this program:

```
import pygame
import random
import math
import sys

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gameSize = (1200,800)

gameSurface = pygame.display.set_mode(gameSize)
pygame.display.set_caption('Green Balls!')



class GreenBall:               # Your class
    def __init__(self, x, y, size):  # The function that creates a ball at a given x and y position
        self.x = x
        self.y = y 
        self.size = size

    def grow(self):        # Every time this function is called, your ball will grow
        self.size += 1

    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(gameSurface, (0,255,0), (self.x,self.y), (self.size))



ballList = []

def newBall(x, y):       # Initialize a new greenBall at x and y
    global ballList
    ballList.append( GreenBall( x, y, 1 ))





timer = 0

spawnBallTime = 30

while True:      #game loop
    gameSurface.fill((0,0,0))

    for i in ballList:
        i.grow()
        i.render()

    if timer == spawnBallTime:
        newBallX = random.randint(100, gameSize[0]-100)
        newBallY = random.randint(100, gameSize[1]-100)

        newBall(newBallX, newBallY)

        spawnBallTime -= 1
        timer = 0

    timer += 1

    clock.tick(20)

    pygame.display.update()

    event = pygame.event.get()
    for e in event:
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

I don't want to spoil you the fun of writing a fun game, but here is a basic setup I created. Feel free to ask me questions about what any of this means :D

Comment: I will try it. Thank  u bro!

Comment: How can i see what color is under the cursor when I click?

Comment: Here's one way:

    `if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == True:`
          `colorAtMouse = yourSurface.get_at(pygame.mouse.get_pos())`

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `Ball`. The class has 3 attributes. The position (`self.x`, `self.y`) a nd the current size (`self.size`). The call has to methods. `change_size` changes the size of the a ball and `draw_ball` draws the ball:

```py
class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0,500)
        self.y = random.randint(0,500)
        self.size = 1

    def change_size(self):
        self.size += 1
        if self.size > 100:
            self.size = 1

    def draw_ball(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, YELLOW, (self.x, self.y), self.size)
```

Create a instance of `Ball`, change the size of the ball and draw the ball in the application loop:

```py
ball = Ball()
run_game = True
while run_game:

    tickrate = clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    screen.blit(background,background_rect)
    ball.change_size()
    ball.draw_ball(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```